# Jest/Enzyme/Reactjs testing function used by react component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Hi I have this function (apiCall) that calls an API inside a component and uses the data to update state (to then render a chart with chartjs). I want to test specifically the process inside componentDidMount that updates state without calling the API. After lots of time spent searching for a way of mocking this I still haven't been able to figure it out. Trying to assert the changed state from a mock apiCall function.

this is the apiCall function:

```
const apiCall = (uri) => {
    return fetch(uri)
      .then( (res) => {
         return res
      })
      .catch( (ex) => {
         return 0
      })
 }

 export default apiCall;

// and this is the componentDidMount

componentDidMount() {
      apiCall(this.props.uri)
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({ data: result });
      })
      this.setState({ legend: this.props.legend })
  }
```

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/346#issuecomment-304535773

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use fetch-mock

http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/

Answer (score 0):

Use proxyquire and mock promise function